# Is it important to consider GBP of transimpedance amplifier while choosing feedback resistor?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have designed a circuit which uses AD8630 transimpadance amplifier to amplify incoming current to voltage. The GBP of this amplifier is 2.5 MHz and I'm thinking using 5 mega ohm or 10 mega ohm as a feedback resistor instead of 1 mega ohm so that I can further increase the amplification. Is it feasible to use 5 or 10 mega ohm resistor? will it have any consequence on the performance of the circuit. Kindly share your thoughts. I have attached the circuit below.[image]

Comment: What is your input signal bandwidth and what made you choose a 1 uF feedback capacitor?

Answer (score 3):

It's a great little amplifier but isn't suited to your power supply regime: -

[image]

Your circuit has it connected to a supply of net voltage 10 volts and it ain't going to like that: -

[image]

Also, the worst case input bias current of the op-amp is 1.5 nA and, through a 10 MΩ feedback resistor is going to produce an offset voltage of 15 mV. This would make it's exceptional offset voltage performance wasted. In other words, you'd be better served with an op-amp that has got a significantly lower input bias current at the expense of a worsened input offset voltage.